# How to show the custom field Help text in a Visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field

Hi I have a Custom field with the Help text.

I have used the field in VF page using the attribute `<apex:inputField>` however it is not showing the help text?

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Shipping Information" id="shippinginformation" columns="1" rendered="{!order.Type=='Physical Clock'}">                
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Ship_to__c}" />     
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_Attention__c}" /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_Attention_Email__c}" /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_Attention_Phone__c}" html-placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" id="pho" onkeypress="validatePhone(event, '{!$Component.pho}');" /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_Street__c}" /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Suite_Floor_Address_2__c}" /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_City__c}" /> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_State__c}" />                         
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_Postal_Code__c}" />        
                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_Country__c}"  /> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I have included the custom field and VF page images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you done `
showHeader="false" ` in your page?

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes Show Header is false.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have done `showheader="false"` then you might need to find some other workaround.

Instead of `ShowHeader=false` you can hide the header using some CSS and then use `showHeader="true`

```
<style type="text/css">
.bPageHeader {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Also use the `inputField` inside `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` and your help text will be visible.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
     <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_Postal_Code__c}" />        
     <apex:inputField value="{!order.Shipping_Country__c}"  /> 
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```